# How to Style Specific Rel Link with CSS

Tags: css, hyperlink, rel

I have a website where there is a table which lists my posts, and the categories are displayed next to them. I want to "display:none" on all the categories except one. The issue is they are all specific to a "rel" link. Let me show you an example of the code:

```
<table>
<td class="col-categories">
<a href="example.org" rel="category tag">No Limit</a>
</td>
</table>
```

So basically I'm trying to be able to grab that specific "No Limit" label in the CSS. This is as far as I got, but as of right now it's grabbing all the "rel" links, and I can't get it more specific.

```
td.col-categories a[rel="category tag"] {display:none;}
```

Comment: You can't write style selectors based on text content, you would need javascript for that.

Comment: It's working on firefox. Which browser do you use?

Comment: Try using `:nth-child(n)` to select the specific label. This only works if the label is positioned at a specific location in the table

Comment: Your selector works fine for me ```td.col-categories a[rel="category tag"]```

Comment: So how should your code distinguish between the relevant elements? Can you use `id`, `class`, `data-*` or another attribute?

Comment: @FernandoZamperin I think the OP wants something more specific than that selector based on the text of the element ... he says _"I'm trying to be able to grab that specific "No Limit" label in the CSS"_

Comment: Thanks @zgood, now I get it, I think it's not possible to have a selector based on the value inside the tag, another option would be declare a data-content attribute for example with the same value as the text and then select it, or It would be better to use javascript to do this.